# How to structure search query and for twitter-esque feed?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've seen the firefeed example, but unfortunately it's a little lacking in functionality and I'm not sure how to move forward.

Given a data structure of users and posts:

```
{
  "posts":
    "12": {
      "uid": 14,
      "message": "This is my message @16 @55"
      "timestamp": 1459361875666
      "mentions": {
        0: 16,
        1: 55
      }
    }
    "13": {  
      "uid": 55,
      "message": "This is another message"
      "timestamp": 1469861245622,
      "mentions": null
    }
  }

  "users": {
    "14": {
      "following": {
        1: 16,
        2: 55
      }
    }
    "16": {
      "following": {
        0: 55
      }
    }
    "55": {
      "following": {
        0: 14
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How would I construct the query to bring back all the posts for users I'm following, as well as the posts I'm mentioned in? I can't find any *recent* documentation on advanced queries...

For example, if I am user 16, I should see all posts by user 55 (a user I am following) PLUS the post (id 12) by user 14 since they mentioned me in descending timestamp order.

Should I rethink the way the data is structured for performance purposes?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: restructured IDs to be unique

Answer (score 1):

> all the posts for users I'm following

```
// Reference
var ref = firebase.database().ref("users").child("some-user").child("following");
// Data call
ref.once("value).then(function(snapshot) {
    // Iterate each following
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        // value
        var childData = childSnapshot.val();
        var followRef = firebase.database().ref("posts").orderByChild("uid").equalTo(i);
        followRef.once("value").then(function(grandChildSnapshot) {
            // RETURN OF ALL POSTS
        }
    });
});
```

**Objects must have unique keys inside so for your data structure make sure they're not all called `post`, I recommend using `push()` and they would all get unique ids.**

> posts I'm mentioned in?

```
"users": {
"user": {
  "id": 14,
  "following": {
    1: 16,
    2: 55
  },
  mentioned: {
     some-post: the-user,
     ...
  }
}
...
```

You can keep your data structure the way it is, but also add to each follower the posts he is mentioned in.

```
// When post is pushed, get all users mentioned
...
var ref = firebase.database().ref("users").child(some-mentioned-user).child("mentioned");
ref.update({ <some-post> : <user-who-posted> });
```

After

```
var mentionedRef = firebase.database().ref("users").child(some-mentioned-user).child("mentioned");
mentionedRef.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
    // Iterate each following
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        // key
        var childKey = childSnapshot.key();
        var postRef = firebase.database().ref("posts").child(childKey);
        postRef.once("value").then(function(grandChildSnapshot) {
             // RETURN OF ALL POSTS
        })
    });
});
```

Comment with any questions.

Comment: Adding mentions to a user doesn't seem very sustainable. Let's say a user is mentioned in 100,000 posts, wouldn't that mean the user would now have 100,000 points of data? (100,000+ is a realistic number for some users in my system)

Also, each post has already has unique id in the structure... what am I missing? posts > post > id (unique)

Comment: 1. If you do not store what posts the user is mentioned in then how will you query it? Iterate through every single post on the entire site?
2. posts > **post** > id, that needs to be unique I believe.

Comment: And if the user is mentioned in 100,000 posts, that is at least less than the number of total posts you would need to search through.

Comment: Can the mentions not be indexed to prevent a full scan though?

Comment: Yes, but then you are still retrieving all posts with at least 1 mention which is still greater then all the posts 1 user is mentioned in.

Comment: Hmm, I'll have to play around with it and see what actually ends up being faster. Edited the json so that it has a unique key.